# Value of type "[String : String]" has no member 'major'

Tags: iphone, string, swift, types, ibeacon

When I want to add `String(beacons[index].major.stringValue)` for example in my dictionary I get the following error:

> Value of type "[String : String]" has no member 'major'

```
if(beacons.count > 0) {
    let nearestBeacon:CLBeacon = beacons[0]
    for var index = 0; index < beacons.count; index++ {
        let uuidString = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        var beacons: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []
        beacons.append(["uuid": uuidString, "major": String(beacons[index].major.stringValue), "minor": beacons[index].minor.stringValue, "accurency": String(beacons[index].accuracy)])
        Server.beaconsSend(beacons) { // success, data in
            print(data)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you created a beacons dictionary while you are in a condition (if else) on a beacons array. 
The beacons you created now hides the beacon array, and you are refering only to the dictionary

Comment: Thanks you that's it !

Comment: Happy to help. And please accept as the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
var beacons: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []
```

is shadowing your original `beacons` array. This means that within the scope in which it is defined (the body of the for loop), the compiler thinks `beacons` always refers to the array of dictionaries. The simple answer is to just rename it:

```
for var index = 0; index < beacons.count; index++ {
    let uuidString = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    var myBeacons: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []
    myBeacons.append(["uuid": uuidString, "major": String(beacons[index].major.stringValue), "minor": beacons[index].minor.stringValue, "accurency": String(beacons[index].accuracy)])
    Server.beaconsSend(myBeacons) { // success, data in
        print(data)
    }
}
```